# WordPress pagination not working for get_posts() function?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, pagination

I have make one Template and assign a template to testimonial page.
All the below code is placed inside my template file.

My problem is that `Next`and `Prev` links are not even displaying on Testimonial page. I want to use only `get_posts` query to retrieve data.

How can I display pagination for `get_posts`?

```
global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;

$postsPerPage = 2;
$postOffset = $paged * $postsPerPage;

$args_testimonial = array(
'post_type' => 'testimonial',
'offset'          => $postOffset,
'posts_per_page'  => $postsPerPage,
'orderby'=> 'title',
'order'=>'DESC'
);

$data_testimonial = get_posts( $args_testimonial ); 



foreach ( $data_testimonial as $post_testimonial ) : setup_postdata( $post_testimonial ); 

                $testimonee_title = get_the_title($post_testimonial->ID);
                $testimonee_post = get_post($post_testimonial->ID);
                $testimonee_content = $testimonee_post->post_content; 
                $testimonee_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_testimonial->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );




       if ( $testimonee_title || $testimonee_content || $testimonee_image ) { ?>
        <div class="single-testimonial">
        <?php if ( $testimonee_content ) { ?>
            <div class="testimonial-content">
                <p>Dear Gary’s Carpet Cleaning</p>
                <p><?php echo $testimonee_content; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php } 

            if ( $testimonee_title || $testimonee_image ) { ?>
            <div class="testimonial-person">
                <div class="testimonial-image">
                <?php if ( $testimonee_image ) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $testimonee_image[0]; ?>" alt=" "/>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/testimonial-dummy-image.png" alt=" "/>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                    <?php if( $testimonee_title ) { ?>
                <div class="testimonial-name">
                    <p><strong>-<?php echo $testimonee_title; ?></strong></p>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <?php } endforeach; 
        next_posts_link( 'Prev'); 
        previous_posts_link('Next'); 
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @rowmoin Not yet, I have posted this question for solution

Comment: I have tried to give a solution in bellow answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use `get_posts` if you need paginated queries.

I think the easiest and most appropriate here is to make use of `WP_Query` to construct your custom query
I do think that `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` is better to use with `WP_Query`

```
global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;

$postsPerPage = 2;
$postOffset = $paged * $postsPerPage;

$args_testimonial = array(
'post_type' => 'testimonial',
'offset'          => $postOffset,
'posts_per_page'  => $postsPerPage,
'orderby'=> 'title',
'order'=>'DESC'
);
$postslist = new WP_Query( $args_testimonial );

    if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); 
            the_title();
        endwhile;
        next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $postslist->max_num_pages );
        previous_posts_link( 'Next Entries &raquo;' ); 
        wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this replace your pagination code but am not sure it will be work or not:

```
 <?php 
 {$paged=$_GET['current-page'];}else{$paged=1;}
 $total_pages=$data_testimonial ->max_num_pages;
 if($total_pages>1){$current_page=$paged;
 ?>
<?php
      echo '<ul class="pagination"><li >';
      $big=999999999;
      echo paginate_links (array('base'=>@add_query_arg('current-page','%#%'),
      'format'=>'?current-page=%#%','current'=>$current_page,'total'=>$total_pages,'mid_size'=>4,'type'=>'plain',
      'prev_next'=>True,));
      echo '</li>
      </ul>';?>
<?php }wp_reset_postdata();wp_reset_query();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked everywhere finally after long time i solved this.

```
   <?php 
     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
           $postsPerPage=9;
           $postOffset = $paged * $postsPerPage;
           
           $past_events = get_posts( 
              array( 
              'product_cat' => 'past-events',    
              'numberposts'  => $postsPerPage, 
              'post_type'    => 'product',
              'order'        => 'DESC',
              'offset'       =>  $postOffset-$postsPerPage,
              ) 
            );
foreach($past_events as $key => $val){
   print_r($val);
}
```

Comment: Pratab
Is there way to get total number of posts in same get_posts method? (without using extra query.)

Comment: I think for that another query is better.